# rails 3 destroy action problem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, action, destroy

i am trying to delete some rows on my database but when i call destroy action, update action works.

this is delete.html.haml

```
 =form_for @post, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @post.id} do |f|
```

this is route

```
resources :post
    root :to => "post#index"
    match '/delete/:id/', :to => "post#delete"
```

What's the problem? Anybody does understand?

Answer (score 1):

The `:action` should be `delete`, to match the name of the action in your controller:

```
= form_for @post, :url => {:action => 'delete', :id => @post.id} do |f|
```

Comment: no. That's not work. I have been tried. I can't understand. How can destroy action go to update action when i call the destroy?

Answer (score 1):

If you are **using rails 3** then you need to make sure you have <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in your header. I put mine after my <%= javascript_include_tag... %> tags.  Also make sure that you include the rails.js.  (This will be on your layout files).

More details here: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38460  Look toward the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The `root` entry in your routes should be placed *after* the `match`block. Plus: seems like you mixed up the controller action and the http verb: use `delete` in the form action and `destroy` in the controller action call:

`=form_for @post, :url => {:action => 'delete', :id => @post.id} do |f|`

`resources :post
    match '/delete/:id/', :to => "post#destroy"
    root :to => "post#index"`